# Removing duplicates within list without creating a new list while preserving order

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

Input:

```
glist = [1,4,2,5,2,2]
```

Expected output:

```
[1,4,2,5]
```

As you can see, I just want to remove the duplicates, the order of elements I want it to be same

Usual way to remove duplicates:

```
def remove(glist):
    result = []
    for ele in glist:
        if ele not in result:
            result.append(ele)
    return result
```

However, this code will create a new list, which is `result`.
I just want to remove the duplicates, WITHOUT creating new list/set. Meaning I want `return glist` as show below
My python: IDLE 3.3
Thanks guys!!!

Presentation of expected code:

```
def remove(glist):
    '''code'''
    return glist
```

Comment: Use a `set` `glist = list(set(glist))`

Comment: @karthikr: that will violate the OP's wish for the original order to be preserved.

Comment: It's not clear what "without creating [a] new list" means.  Are you just looking for `glist[:] = result` instead of `return result`?  (Note that there are more efficient ways to remove duplicates, esp. if your values are hashable, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order?rq=1)).

Comment: @DSM Hi, thanks for the comment, I have edited the question, I am not looking for `glist[:] = result` or `return result`, I want to return `glist` as it is the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the contents are hashable, you can do it this way without creating any list object in your code:

```
def remove(glist):
    seen = set()
    def unseen():
        for val in glist:
            if not val in seen:
                yield val
                seen.add(val)
    glist[:] = unseen()
    return glist # if you must
```

It's a bit of a cheat, since in effect `glist[:] = unseen()` does construct a list from the output of the generator function `unseen()` and then (efficiently) transfer its contents to `glist`. It may not actually construct a list object, but it uses about the same amount of memory as if it did, because the old contents of `glist` of course aren't freed until the new array is completed.

If the contents aren't hashable, or if you've plenty of time but no memory to spare, then I suppose you'll have to do it the slow way:

```
idx = 0
while idx < len(glist):
    if glist[idx] in glist[0:idx]:
        del glist[idx]
    else:
        idx += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> glist = [1,4,2,5,2,2]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> glist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(glist))
>>> glist
[1, 4, 2, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler version of Alex's answer (which is perfectly valid) would be:

```
glist = [1,4,2,5]
glist = set(glist)
print glist
```

A set cannot have duplicates, so making a list into a set removes all duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't preserve order.

Comment: @Ajax: Thanks for the reply, but I need to preserve the order, and I think `set` is consider a new list/set as I need to use the original list which is `glist`